# How do we reference one foreign key with multiple tables?

Tags: python, django, database

I am trying access two tables with one foreign key.

```
from table1.models import tab1
from table2.models import tab2


class Case(models.Model):
table = models.ForeignKey(tab1,tab2, blank=True,null=True 
                                            ,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: ... and the outcome is...? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, what outcome to you expect/want? Given what you're asking, what would `my_case.table.foo` mean?

Comment: there's a model.py which gives me all the details of the table. The 'table' variable give me the id of the table. Moreover i just want to keep one variable which stores all the table ids and tells me which id its referencing in a particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this one foreign key to each field.
    Like

```
from table1.models import tab1
from table2.models import tab2
class Case(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(tab1)
    table 2 = models.ForeignKey(tab2)
```

Because foreign key should be unique.
   So you cannot assign two key to one field

Comment: yeah but what if i want to use just one foriegn key which can tell me which table it is referenced to

Comment: if you want to use one foreign key than you can do like this                                table = models.ForeignKey(tab1)                                                             
Here tab1 would be the model name which you want use.